# Where is the "stack tool" for android dev? (to help debug native c++ code)

Tags: android, stack, android-ndk

I am writing an android game that involves some c++.
I have a fairly repeatable crash that seems to be due to my c++ code

Looking at the page:
http://source.android.com/porting/debugging_native.html#Debug_Scenarios
(right at the end)

it says to run the output through the "stack tool" - which I can find no trace of.. nor aproto.

Comment: Ive got the bug prompting this question fixed, but am still interested to know the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/73f89bb8739c24bb/5228e7a5dcfff090?lnk=gst&q=stack+tool#5228e7a5dcfff090

It seems the stack tool is an internal google tool (despite being in public docs...)

Answer (score 3):

I think they're referring to this:

http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/

Don't feel bad about not finding it; it took a lot of searching to track it down the first time. :)

Comment: Looks Handy - but its not the tool they are referring to. compare its output ( http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-stacktrace-analyzer/wiki/Usage ) with theoutput at the bottom of this page ( http://source.android.com/porting/debugging_native.html#Debug_Scenarios )

Comment: Fun; I see what you mean. Have you asked about it on the NDK list? The Googlers there might be able to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

OK - not the nice clean solution Im looking for, but: http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-04/msg00492.html
addr2line - lets me see where Im crashing, in my main loop!

I think I'm not being thread safe...

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the docs seem to be referring to the [ndk-stack tool](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html) (even though they call it "the stack tool").